# Promise 'then' is not a function when using the 'ui-router'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

the config:

```
.state('index.usermng.userInfo',{
        url: '/userInfo/:id',
        templateUrl: 'tpls/userInfo.html',
        controller: 'userInfoCtrl',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: function($http, serverUrl, $stateParams){
                return $http.get(serverUrl + "/user/info?userId=" + $stateParams.id);
            }
        }
    })
```

the controller:

```
//UsrInfo Controller
userApp.controller('userInfoCtrl', ['$scope', 'userInfo', function($scope, userInfo) {
userInfo.then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data
})
```

I defined the 'userInfo' in the 'ui-router' config.js,when i want to use it in the controller,causing 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your resolve should be:

From [$routeParams docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams):

> Note that the **$routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully**. This means that **you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions**. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

So just inject `$route` instead of `$routeParams`:

```
resolve: {
    userInfo: function($http, serverUrl,  $route){
      return $http.get(serverUrl + "/user/info?userId=" + $route.current.params.id)
      .then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      })
    }
}
```

This way, the `resolve function` returns you the `response` , so in your controller, you can have:

```
$scope.data = userInfo
```

## More on promise

If your `resolve function` returns you a `promise` (which is not in your case), it can be accessed using $promise.

#### Promise Example (using `$resource`)

```
.factory('userInfo', ['serverUrl', '$resource', function (serverURL, $resource) {
    return $resource(serverUrl + '/user/info?userId=');
}]);
```

From the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>    collection object, updated with data from server...

So in this case, in your controller should be:

```
userInfo.$promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response
})
```

Comment: thanks,when I modified as you told me,causing：‘TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined’

Answer (score 1):

This is how I setup my resolves, see if this works for you:

```
resolve: {
    userInfo: function($http, serverUrl, $stateParams){
        return $http.get(serverUrl + "/user/info?userId=" + $stateParams.id).then(function(response){
return response.data});
    }
}
```

Then in your controller `userInfo` is resolved and you won't need to wait for it to resolve.

Comment: thanks,it works,but I still don't understand why I can't use the promise in the controller,could you explain that for me?

Comment: The controller is called only when userInfo is resolved, so when the code in your controller is run userInfo has already been resolved. Therefore in your code, userInfo is the response object, the data is in userInfo.data.